# How to run the same JQuery on a new page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I was wondering, is it ever possible to run a JQuery code on the next page (lets say Page 2) that is executed on another page before (lets say Page 1)?

So lets say this block was executed on Page 1

```
const redirectToAnotherPage = document.querySelector(".redirect")
console.log("executed")
redirectToAnotherPage.click()
```

When `redirectToAnotherPage.click()` is executed, a new page `Page2` will be loaded, so my question is, is it possible to run the above code on Page2 automatically? Without typing any code again, or is it impossible because a new page loads a new console and a new html page?

I'm working on an automation script and I want to execute a code block on multiple pages, when a page opens another one, and I want to continue executing the same code on the new pages without typing it again.

Comment: A page render will only execute whatever code is present on that page - if you do not provide the instructions on the page to execute this code, then it simply won't do it; there is no way to instruct or pass code between pages; the only thing that I can think of is sending the code through a POST request as a string, and loading it on the next page however this is a significant security risk.

Comment: The windows and internal documents created for each page are completely insulated and know nothing about each other nor can access each other. The Page 1 window is completely wiped out and replaced by a new window instance when Page 2 is loaded

Comment: One common approach to such a situaltion is to pass a url search parameter or  hash in the next page url and read that with code in Page 2 and react accordingly there

Answer (score 0):

It would be the latter. You can't exactly control the page you're next to. There's one workaround that I can think of. Send an AJAX request to the (relative) page you want to redirect to, change the window location with `history.pushState()`, and re-write the document with the HTML received from the AJAX request. I once made a similar implementation for reference: [`a-ejs`](https://github.com/codingjlu/a-e). Hope that makes sense.